# Select multiple rows in gridview on mouse drag in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a check box column, on dragging mouse over the rows the corresponding rows are to be highlighted and the checkboxes also should be selected. Is it possible to select multiple rows in a gridview on mouse drag using ASP.Net? This functionality is implemented using Telerik controls, one such example is found in [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/selecting/defaultcs.aspx) link

I have to implement this functionality in ASP.Net itself without using any third party controls!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQGrid's](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) Custom multi select feature or [dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid.](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid.html)

Comment: That control is not relevant to my requirement! I want the gridview rows to be selected on mouse drag!